# Extended Hashmaps

Tags: c++, hashmap, extend

So I've been searching around the C++ forums and haven't really found a solution. I am attempting to create an extended hashmap with the following details:
Able to store values of either real or string.
Able to store keys of either real or string.
Able to store multiple entries(values) per key.

An example look of a result:

key: "key" --> value: 0,5,"45","66".

key: 55 --> value: "Yo", 27, "67",88.

As you can see, I am looking to create a hashmap where I can store a key as either real or string + being able to store multiple keys as either real or string per key.

Comment: [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)?

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ is a statically-typed language, you have to either template whatever class you create for this, or you have to define a specific type for the key and value.  Alternatively, you could use the built-in `map<T>` type which is available in the standard template library, but again - there isn't a way to sense which type you need to use for the template parameter of `map<T>` at runtime.

You may be able to use something like a bidirectional map, though.  Boost has one, and here's the code for one I wrote recently:

```
// bimap.h

#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T0, typename T1>
class bimap
{
public:
    bimap(){}

    bool Insert(T0, T1);
    void Clear();

    T0& operator[](T1);
    T1& operator[](T0);

private:
    list<pair<T0, T1>> m_dictionary;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
bool bimap<T0, T1>::Insert(T0 key, T1 value)
{
    for (list<pair<T0, T1>>::const_iterator cur = m_dictionary.begin(); cur != m_dictionary.end(); cur++)
    {
        if ((*cur).first == key)
            return false;
    }

    m_dictionary.push_back(make_pair(key, value));
    return true;
}

template<typename T0, typename T1>
void bimap<T0, T1>::Clear()
{
    m_dictionary.clear();
}

template<typename T0, typename T1>
T0& bimap<T0, T1>::operator[](T1 key)
{
    for (list<pair<T0, T1>>::iterator cur = m_dictionary.begin(); cur != m_dictionary.end(); cur++)
    {
        if ((*cur).second == key)
            return (*cur).first;
    }

    throw new out_of_range("Key does not exist.");
}

template<typename T0, typename T1>
T1& bimap<T0, T1>::operator[](T0 value)
{
    for (list<pair<T0, T1>>::iterator cur = m_dictionary.begin(); cur != m_dictionary.end(); cur++)
    {
        if ((*cur).first == value)
            return (*cur).second;
    }

    throw new out_of_range("Value does not exist.");
}
```

The advantage of a bidirectional map is that you are able to access a key by using a value or a value using a key.  The downside (at least with my code, but I imagine with the boost class as well) is that it doesn't allow for multiple values per key.  But it wouldn't be hard to modify my code to allow this.  You would just have to modify the `Insert()` method, and then think about what should be returned from the `operator[]` which takes a key and returns a value if there are multiple values for a given key.  I haven't thought about this much, but off the top of my head, I think it could return an iterator which could be used to iterate through the key's values.

Comment: Well, boost takes ages to install. So I'll try it out when it's all done. As for the map<T> idea I'll look into that as I currently have no idea what's going on there. Down to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allergic to boost, you might want to take a look at [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html). You could use `boost::variant<double, std::string>` as both the key and value type in a hash multimap, or you could use `std::vector<boost::variant<double, std::string>>` as the value type in a hashmap.

Among its other virtues (like type-safety), a `boost::variant` type is hashable as long as all of its member types are hashable (and both `double` and `std::string` are), so you should be able to use them as keys in a hash table.